# How can I add wireless mobile node location to statistic collection in OMNeT++ with INET4?

Tags: c++, omnet++

I am trying to run a simulation in OMNeT++ to collect throughput with respect to a mobile wireless node location. I need to be able to collect the x and y coordinates of a node as a vector over the course of the simulation. It does not appear that any module automatically records the location of a node, and I have not been able to use cOutVector to add it myself.

None of the mobility modules I found (mostly using TurtleMobility, but I looked at several others) seem to record the node's position. I have also tried to record them manually with cOutVectors and signals, but I have not had success, as most of the important functions in INET are defined as const, and the cOutVectors functions and the emit() function for signals both seem to require non-const items (the cOutVector or sigsim_t) to operate on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [signal](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/b02f7bedb7b7168640de465d476190af946ce6ac/src/inet/mobility/base/MobilityBase.ned#L28C17-L28C37), which is emitted on every update of mobility model. However, it is not added to the final statistic by default for some reason.

So, you may redefine the same signal in your application or in your host module but with `@statistic` directive in the ned file, [like here](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/b02f7bedb7b7168640de465d476190af946ce6ac/examples/mobility/MobileHost.ned). [Here is more](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part5/#53-statistic-collection-without-modifying-your-model) about signal+statistic mechanism of data aggregation.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly what I needed.
I noticed this signal previously, but I didn't know how to get information from it. Where did you find that you can use `source=xCoord(mobilityPos(signalName))` to get the x coordinate? I don't see those in the code (NED or C++) anywhere. There is other information I need to get from other nodes, and knowing how to get this information will be really helpful.

Comment: it is an archaic but still valid inet syntax, where filters are used: https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/b02f7bedb7b7168640de465d476190af946ce6ac/src/inet/common/ResultFilters.cc#L122
If you want to work with signals in the code, I suggest you to look at more straightforward example: https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/b02f7bedb7b7168640de465d476190af946ce6ac/src/inet/visualizer/base/MobilityVisualizerBase.cc#L79 (subscribe), https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/b02f7bedb7b7168640de465d476190af946ce6ac/src/inet/visualizer/base/MobilityVisualizerBase.cc#L124 (process)

Comment: to put it more simply: you can subscribe to any signal in the parent-to-child direction and by overriding `receiveSignal` of your receiver OMNeT++ module with pattern matching, you may decide what to do with each incoming update of your subscribed value(s).